# How to put browser's native login prompt in JSP and retrieve the username & password

Tags: jsp, servlets, loginview

I want the web browser to ask for username and password using it's default login prompt like this.
[image: Firefox Login Prompt]
I read about how to implement it [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/25/using-the-browsers-native-login-prompt/) but it is for ASP. I want it done in JSP or servlet and I also want to know that how will I receive those username and password in my servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `BASIC` authentication. You need to use `JAAS` for the same. 
[This tutorial](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/07/configure-jdbcrealm-jaas-for-mysql-and-tomcat-7-with-form-based-authentication/) provides `FORM` based authentication. but as you want `BASIC` authentication, you need to

```
<login-config>
     <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

You can retrieve the user principal as follows

```
request.getUserPrincipal().getName().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Basic authentication for this you can refer following link, it gives basic authentication using servlet.

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

It configures basic authentication in web.xml
Also, you need to add

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="yourname" password="yourpassword" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="test" password="test"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

in tomcat-users.xml

Example link :
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html?page=1

Hope it helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void  doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("windows-31j");
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=windows-31j");
    String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (auth == null)
    {
      response.setStatus(401); 
      response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); 
      response.setDateHeader("Expires",0); 
      response.setHeader("WWW-authenticate","Basic Realm=\"AuthDemo Server\""); 

    } else {
        response.getWriter().print("Authorization :" + request.getHeader("Authorization"));
    }

            }
      }
```